# Open-source / Inexpensive CRM?

Tags: open-source, cms, crm

I'm looking for something lightweight, I don't mind if it's using something like Joomla/Drupal with extensions/plugins but it needs to have a few key features:

- Front facing website, ability to create pages etc... A simple CMS will do.
- An area for customers, ability to view things like invoices, create support tickets and download files.

That's really it, to be honest I don't even know of paid solutions and I'm struggling to find any solution out there.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [SugarCRM](https://www.sugarcrm.com/) and [vTiger](https://www.vtiger.com/). Both of these are:

- free and open source
- very popular
- coming with lots of plugins (both free and commercial)
- written in PHP and able to integrate with Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress etc.
- easy and cheap to setup
- easy to extend with own plugins

Answer (score 2):

[Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) is for sure something worth considering. If you'd add a '*module*' (= a plugin) like the (fairly popular) [Support Ticketing System](https://www.drupal.org/project/support) module, you'd already be pretty close to what you're looking for.

Maybe you also want to check if any of the '[Drupal Distributions](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_distribution?f%5B0%5D=&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=drupal_core%3A103&f%5B3%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&text=&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage%20desc&op=Search)' could fit your needs. These distributions are like a set of pre-packaged modules to address specific needs (and typically require less Drupal experience to get you going). Just to mention a few (popular) ones (checkout the links for more details):

- [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium).
- [Drupal Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons).
- [Open Enterprise](https://www.drupal.org/project/openenterprise).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at Rubedo:

- it is scalable, which means that you can start small (and then easily grow if needed),
- it has a back office that is designed to be used by any kind of contributor (because not all of them are developers),
- it has a "front facing website" (because it is a website manager).
- it is Open-source.

The best thing about it is that there is a [demo](https://demo.rubedo-project.org/en/): you don't have to install it to try it and see whether it fits your needs or not.

Comment: Rubedo seems to be dead